# Wired output in console while running a React app

Tags: reactjs

when I run the app there is an array of URLs getting outputted in the console containing some of (not all) the website URLs that I have visited.

**the console** :

> [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
>
> Array(2)
>
> 0:
> "https://erpbasic.blogspot.com/2012/01/inheritance-advantages-and.html"
>
> 1: "https://dev.to/johnstonlogan/react-hooks-barney-style-1hk7"
>
> length: 2
>
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

the output is coming from a file called **content.js** line 11

**the function that is outputting to the console is** :

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(null, (res) => {

if(res.urls){
  console.log(res.urls)
 if(res.urls.includes(window.location.href)){
    addStyleSheet()
 }
 else {
   res.urls.forEach(element => {
     if(element.includes(window.location.href)){
       addStyleSheet()
     }
   });
  }
 }
});
```

it's not a file that is inside the project I think it's a react file why is this happening and how can I remove it.

Thank you!

Comment: the function is adding stylesheet to the project by checking the url with the list of urls your storage contains , if you don't want this functionality then remove the lines of codes you posted there

Comment: @ShoyebMemon I did but the changes get discarded after a reload 
and also a warning icon pops next to the file name when I hover on it, it says   "Changes to this file were not saved to file system"

Comment: are you deploying it somewhere or checking it your localhost ? you can also do search on the entire project ```res.urls``` and check if there is a similar code written somewhere else or not

Comment: it is on my localhost, I didn't find any line that outputs this to the console, and the content.js file is not a file in my project . I didn't create such a file.

Comment: if this is coming in the bundle can you check your ```node_modules``` , there might be possibility of content.js file used by some third part app

Comment: I deleted node_modules and re-run "yarn" and "yarn start" but nothing changed, also my project has only React with no third-party libraries and vanilla CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240865/discussion-between-shoyeb-memon-and-mrxq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to run it in a different browser . it will fix the issue :). this might be a case of extension on one of your browser which is adding its own css file which you are viewing in your console

cheers.

Comment: running it from a different browser worked and running from an incognito mode worked as well, thank you!